# how to save this radio button value to SQL database according echo radio button

Tags: php, html

```
echo '<input class="form-check-input align" type="radio" value="1" name="answer'.$rownumber.' ">'.$one .'';
echo '<input class="form-check-input align " type="radio" value="2"  name="answer'.$rownumber.' ">'. $two.'';
echo '<input class="form-check-input align" type="radio" value="3"  name="answer'.$rownumber.' ">'. $three.'';
echo '<input class="form-check-input align" type="radio" value="4"  name="answer'.$rownumber.' ">'. $four.'';?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuoVB.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] rather than an out of context snippet and a screenshot. See also the [tour] and [ask] to improve your experience here. Lastly...this sounds like standard HTML forms + PHP functionality you could find in many tutorials already. What do you need us for? Where _exactly_ are you stuck? As it stands your post is too vague for anyone to be able to help you. Please read those links and then edit your question before it gets closed. Thankyou

Comment: P.s. when it says "enter image description here"...that's a hint! It's not the title of your image...

Comment: Here is a Question form. The data in the database is displayed here. There are radio buttons for the answers. The student needs to save the marked answers again. how to do that? how to get selected value in the radio button using php .like this one ....

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$ans_one = $_POST['answer'];
echo $ans_one;
}

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69324446/edit) to include your PHP code as well insteaf of posting it as a comment. The posted radio input won't be in `$_POST['answer']` for two reasons; 1. You're appending `$rownumber` to the name and 2. the name contains a trailing space.

Comment: Check your generated HTML in the browser - you're going to end up with `name="answer1"` something like that. Clearly, `$_POST["answer"]` won't match that. You need to use the numbers in your PHP too

Comment: name="answer'.$rownumber.' "

how can i get this name-value to php?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking a multi-choice question exam & you want to store the result in database for the user, right? you can use this gist i wrote for you.

[gist link](https://gist.github.com/abedcodes/6dbc727ed4faad8f1a573fdff9fffb0c)

the reason i divided the code into multiple files is to be more readable. the **main snippet** is in **_render.php** file. at the end, you will have an $answers, which returns the user choices at form's action script, which in my gist i created as assert.php.

[image]

$answers[$question_id] gives you user choice to a question with id of $question_id. for storing in database, you can json_encode($answers) which converts all user's answers to an exam to string which is suitable for storing in a field in database.

the questions are coming from data.php, but for your usage, this is coming from database & each question is a table record i assume.

note that **you don't have to echo the entire html tag** in a foreach() loop. html snippets within closed php tags which determines the domain of a loop will be printed & displayed in user's browser.

```php
    <?php foreach($MCQs as $MCQ):  ?>
        <!-- html here -->
        <p><?php echo $MCQ['stem']; ?></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**you can open & close php tags as many times as you want**(resulting in a cleaner file) & only print & work with parts of data within php tags which you have to process with php.

inputs of type **radio & checkbox** have strange behavior in such way that **if they are unchecked, they won't pass on to the action script at all**!
so for each question we print 4 choices' radio inputs with same name attribute, resulting in:

1. only one of 4 could be selected
2. the answer & question are better related in $answers

you have to tweak my _render.php file if you want to use it, because my naming doesn't match your field's name.

i hope it was helpful, sorry if it became long ;)

Comment: thank you soo much for your answer, it's very helpful for me. im beginner in this field .thank you very very much

Comment: glad it was helpful @Dinesh_M_ Bandara ;) if my answer solved your problem, please accept it & check mark beside my answer, thanks

Comment: yes, thank you so much. I can fix that my problem according to your solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo '<input class="form-check-input align" type="radio" value="1" name="answer'.$rownumber.' ">'.$one;
echo '<input class="form-check-input align " type="radio" value="2"  name="answer'.$rownumber.' ">'. $two;
echo '<input class="form-check-input align" type="radio" value="3"  name="answer'.$rownumber.' ">'. $three;
echo '<input class="form-check-input align" type="radio" value="4"  name="answer'.$rownumber.' ">'. $four;
```

first you have to remove the $rownumber from the name attribute
i am writing the code below

```
echo '<input class="form-check-input align" type="radio" value="1" name="answer">'.$one;
echo '<input class="form-check-input align " type="radio" value="2"  name="answer">'. $two;
echo '<input class="form-check-input align" type="radio" value="3"  name="answer">'. $three;
echo '<input class="form-check-input align" type="radio" value="4"  name="answer">'. $four;
```

then after form submit add the PHP code in PHP file

```
$answer = $_GET['answer'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO dbname(`answer`) VALUES('$answer');
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if( $query ){
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
else{
    echo "FAILED";
}
```

Comment: If you remove it, you will not be able to identify the radio button separately from the ID